# How do you create a colorbox popup on the frontpage of D7?

Tags: javascript

I'm using Colorbox and Drupal 7. I'm trying to create a Colorbox of an Image on the front page in a POP-UP. The problem is I can't figure out how to get it to show up on page load. How can I achieve this without adding an additional elements showing on the frontpage?

Comment: This is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969741/open-colorbox-on-page-load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module: [Splashify](http://drupal.org/project/splashify) did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Views:

- create a view with a block display
- add the field with the image and set the output to colorbox
- add this block to the homepage with [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) or block management

Comment: I dont want to display the block other than the colorbox.

Comment: I didn't understand: what should appears in your homepage?

Comment: My homepage will appear as normal. But initial pageload, it will display a colorbox with an image of my choice.

Comment: But i dont want to add a block on the homepage just to display my colorbox.. unless i'm understanding your explanation wrong.

Comment: Ok, is more clear. You want a "popup", with colorbox, when homepage is loaded, is it right. If is this I can't help you, sorry.

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This module is an option: [Popup On Load](http://drupal.org/project/popup_onload)

> The module allows to display a popup after a certain delay on a page
>   load. This fills a gap in popup modules family (Popups, Popup), which
>   are designed to show popups only after a click on an HTML element, or
>   to implement a complex behavior like modal dialog forms.